# How to calculate String Buffer capacity?

Tags: java, string, stringbuffer, capacity

```
 import java.io.*;

class GFG {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer("AAA");
        int p = s.length();
        int q = s.capacity();
        System.out.println("Length of string =" + p);
        System.out.println("Capacity of string =" + q);
    }
}
```

it gives output:

> Length of string =3 Capacity of string =19

Actually  the  length can be found by the number of characters in string,So I know the direct answer without IDE.But what is exactly way to calculate capacity of a string.How can I get an idea of a string capacity without using any IDE.

Comment: Why do you need to know the capacity of your `StringBuffer`?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, the answer is an implementation detail and can change between Java versions. What do you need this information for? If you can add some more information about your use case into your question it might be easier to answer.

Comment: Agreed: in principle it's an implementational detail. Note that the API does define the public method AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacity() to have the behaviour 'double and add 2'. I don't think there's any absolute guarantee that this method and the internal method used when you call append() will actually be the same, but so far they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The capacity is the size of the internal buffer. You usually only care about when you pre-size the buffer for constructing a string you already know the maximum size of.
String buffers/builders automatically increase their capacity when they need to.